# How do I get ILSVRC12 data in image format or how to create ilsvrc12_val_lmdb?

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe, imagenet

I am trying to run imagenet example in Caffe. In this(https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/examples/imagenet) page they say

```
We assume that you already have downloaded the ImageNet training data and validation data, and they are stored on your disk like:

/path/to/imagenet/train/n01440764/n01440764_10026.JPEG
/path/to/imagenet/val/ILSVRC2012_val_00000001.JPEG
```

Where do I find this data?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a process.
1. Got to [imagenet's download](http://image-net.org/download) page and select "Download Image URLs".
2. Download the image URL list from the links at the bottom of the page, e.g., [fall 2011's list](http://image-net.org/imagenet_data/urls/imagenet_fall11_urls.tgz).
3. Download the images from their URLs (this may take a few days).

Note that some of the URLs (~5% last time I checked) are no longer valid, and will return a "stub" flickr image.

Here's a perl script I used to download the images using [`convert` utility](https://www.howtogeek.com/109369/how-to-quickly-resize-convert-modify-images-from-the-linux-terminal/):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5_hex);
use File::Copy;

my $base = "/path/to/imagenet/train/";

open my $fh, '/path/to/train_image_urls.txt' or die "Cannot not open url list: $!";
while( my $line = <$fh> )  {
    # a line in the url list looks like:
    # n00005787_13    http://www.powercai.net/Photo/UploadPhotos/200503/20050307172201492.jpg
    chomp($line);
    if ( $line =~ /^(n\d+)_(\d+)\s+(\S.+)$/ ) {
      my $type = $1;
      my $filename = $1 . "_" . $2;
      my $url = $3;
      my $dst = "$base/$type/$filename" . ".JPEG";
      if (! -d $base.$type ) {
        mkdir($base.$type)
      }
      my $convertCmd = "convert \"$url\" $dst";
      if ( system( $convertCmd ) == 0 ) {
         if ( -e $dst ) {
           my $size = -s $dst;
           # check that image is not a "flickr" stub:
           if ( $size == 24921 || $size == 6898 ) {
              open( my $FILE, $dst );
              binmode($FILE);
              my $md5sum = Digest::MD5->new->addfile($FILE)->hexdigest;
              if ( $md5sum eq "513dd080b92472dab22ad3e09f58f1af" || $md5sum == "ed15d4fe8b5680d1b3e01c0d2778d145" ) {
                print $invl "$dst\n";
                move( $dst, $base . "../invalid/" );
              }
              close($FILE);
           }
         }
      } else {
        # invalid image file
      }
    } else {
      # error downloading an image
    }
}
close $fh;
exit(0);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47295025/valueerror-at-image-tensor-tensoractivation-5-softmax0-shape-4-dtyp/47300005?noredirect=1#comment81555441_47300005 any suggestions